# How to edit a message during wait_for in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to edit message during wait_for in discord.py i've tried this:

```py
@bot.command
async def cmd(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("nice")
    m = bot.wait_for("message", check = lambda m : m.author == ctx.author)
    await msg.edit("noice")
```

but this only works after wait_for. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for a message to be displayed while "waiting", the message need to be sent/edited **before** you start waiting. That way, the edit will be shown while waiting

After the wait_for, you can change again the text, like `await msg.edit("not waiting anymore")`

On the other hand if you want to edit your message, for example 2 seconds after you started the wait_for, you will need to do 2 wait_for, the first one with a timeout

```
msg = await ctx.send("nice")
m = bot.wait_for("message", check = lambda m : m.author == ctx.author, timeout=2)
await msg.edit("It has been 2 seconds since I started wait_for")
m = bot.wait_for("message", check = lambda m : m.author == ctx.author)
await msg.edit("noice")
```

This will change the message content to "It has been 2 seconds since I started wait_for" ~2 seconds after the message has been sent